# The meaning of symbols

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What does the following symbols or expression mean?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for these kinds of questions... Moreover, you can easily find an anwser by yourself.

Comment: This question belongs to math.se rather than here.

Comment: We prefer questions that ask about only a single thing at a time.  Here you are asking about multiple expressions and multiple symbols all in the same post.  Also, we prefer posts that are written in a way so that others with the same question are likely to be able to find it by search.  Finally, as others have indicated, this question looks like a question about pure math, without any particular reason why it needs to be answered from a CS perspective.

Comment: @Roukah How exactly is somebody dupposed to find the answer themself? It's not like you can Google for them if you don't know what they're called.

Comment: David, I agree the last expression might be tough to understand for someone unfamiliar with mathematical notation. However, the meaning of the aforementioned symbols is very easy to find. One way would be to use an undergraduate-level math textbook, where notations are most likely explained. Another would be to consult the wikipedia article called "List of mathematical symbols" which "is intended to facilitate finding an unfamiliar symbol by its visual appearance.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ are elements of a set $S$. For example, if $S = \{1, 2, 3\}$, we can select $x = 1$ and $y = 2$.

EDIT:
As pointed out by David below, $*$ could be multiplication or convolution, it's hard to tell from the context.

$\in$ means 'in', that is, that $x$ and $y$ are in a set. We can write 'x and y are elements of the set $S$ ' in math as:

$x, y \in S$

Again, following my example, that would be $1$ and $2$ are in the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

$\forall$ is verbalized 'for all'. It means for every element in the set, something is either true or false. For example:

$\forall x \in S, x < 5$ means that all of the elements in my set $S$ are less than 5.

$I$ is the identity function.

The entire phrase $I: \forall X.  X \rightarrow X$

(EDIT: removed example, as it was misleading)

means the identity function preserves the value of the variable $X$. More concretely, $I$ is the function that maps $X$ to itself. For all values of X, the output of the function is X.

Hope that helps!

Comment: "$*$ is multiplication" How can you be sure? In mathematics, "$x$ times $y$" is probably written 99% of the time as "$xy$", 0.99% of the time as "$x\times y$". It's _very_ unusual to denote multiplication of numbers by $*$ outside programming languages. And I've no idea what you mean by "multiplying two vectors": that's a very strange operation and a bizarre definition of the identity. Also, it's not at all clear that your translation of "$I\colon \forall X.X\to X$" is correct.

Comment: Usually, one uses $\mapsto$ to denote that a function maps some value to some other value, not $\to$. $\to$ is used to denote the type of a function: with $f\colon X\to Y$ meaning that the function $f$ maps values of type $X$ to values of type $Y$. It seems more likely that the expression means something along the lines of "$I$ is a operator that, yields the identify function on every type." But, without knowing the context, it's impossible to say what this and $x*y$ mean.

Comment: Hi David, I've never seen '*' used in any other way, have you? I've seen your second "$x$ X $y$" used to mean a cross-product. I agree that $xy$ is the most common usage. I've seen $\rightarrow$ and $\mapsto$ both used on a blackboard to mean the same thing. Perhaps the wording is different between disciplines, but I think the result is the same: the value of $X$ does not change when operated on by $I$.

Comment: $*$ is often used as a generic group operation. It's also used for convolution of functions, though it would be unusual to denote functions by $x$ and $y$. But not necessarily any more unusual than using $*$ to denote multiplication!

Comment: Interesting. I asked someone else, and they said you're right about convolution (I've never seen that before, thanks for pointing it out). I'll edit my answer accordingly.